# Leafletjs open a popup near a Control button

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet

I'm using [Leafletjs](http://leafletjs.com) to build a map. On that map i have a layer with a big number of markers. When the user click on a marker I remove the global layer and i create a new one with only markers that has some relations with the clicked one.

To make possible for the user return to the precedent(complete) layer, i spawn a button created with [easy-button plugin](https://cliffcloud.github.io/Leaflet.EasyButton/)

```
btnViewAll = L.easyButton(
    'fa-eye', //icon
    function(){
        ea_clearLayer(markersCluster);
        markersCluster.addTo(map);  
    },
    'title',
    ''
);
map.addControl(btnViewAll);
```

but users often don't see it. So i want a temporized popup near this button to tell to them some tips. The Popup class need a LatLng but the [Control class](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#control) don't have *getLatLng()* method.

Here how i have thinked to create and close the popup. But It doesnìt work:

```
var popup = L.popup()
        .setLatLng(btnViewAll.getPosition()) <---- HERE WHAT?
        .setContent("click me to return to all markers")
        .openOn(map);

setInterval(function() {
   popup.closePopup(); 
}, 1000);
```

//UPDATE -----

After a lot of time spent, i can't put a popup in fixed place with @iH8 approch because my openPopup() must spawn after a map.fitBounds(latLng) function that make an animation and move the coordinates already calculated for the popup. The only way to make it work is catch the end fitBounds() event.

My work around is build a div similar to a classic leaflet popup and spawn it with .show():

```
//build a popup content
pcontent='<strong>'+
            "Clicca sull'occhio per poter"+
                '<br/>'+
            'tornare a visualizzare'+
                '<br/>'+
            'tutte le aziende sulla mappa'+
        '</strong>';

//build the popup and appending it
$('#'+map_id).append(ea_custom_popup('popup-tips-viewall',pcontent));

//the popup function
function ea_custom_popup(_class,content){
    return '<div class="'+_class+'" >'+
            '<div class="leaflet-popup-content-wrapper">'+
                '<div class="leaflet-popup-content">'+
                    content+
                '</div>'+
            '</div>'+
            '<div class="leaflet-popup-tip-container">'+
                '<div class="leaflet-popup-tip"></div>'+
            '</div>'+
        '</div>';
}
```

and the show and hide part:

```
...
map.fitBounds(pbounds);

var $popup = $('.popup-tips-viewall');
if(! $popup.hasClass('one-time-viewed')){
    $popup.show();
    $popup.addClass('one-time-viewed');
    setInterval(function() {
        $popup.hide();
    }, 4000);
}
...
```

css:

```
.popup-tips-viewall {
    left: 38px;
    padding: 10px;
    position: relative;
    top: 133px;
    width: 201px;
    z-index: 1;
    opacity:1;
    pointer-events:none;
    overflow:hidden;
    display:none;
}
```

I hope that it can be usefull. Or that someone can tell me the normal(leafletjs way).

Answer (score 0):

That depends on where you place your button. If you've got the exact position of that button you could use the [containerPointToLatLng](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-containerpointtolatlng) function of L.Map to get the coordinates you need for your popup. See the reference for more conversion methods: http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-conversion-methods

Comment: The button spawn every time in the same position, with this function the problem change in: what's the exact position of a point in the map? looking on internet for code

Comment: Hardcoding it, this is a solution to the last question: https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/mouse-position/